# Flutter - how to develop UI? Docs for UI architecture?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I need a manual for developing UI on Flutter.
Not a syntax of Dart or api docs... Something that describes common principles, like hierarchy, core elements and how they interact with each other, and so on.

On android you have activities, which contains `ViewGroup` and `View`, which interact with intents, which stacks when you open new, which pops from stack when closed. For UI you combine Layouts, which contains other Layouts, and ..., which containts simple Views. I need something as described but for Flutter.

Comment: https://flutter.io/widgets-intro/ or https://flutter.io/widgets/ or even https://flutter.io/cookbook/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a few good resources you can check out:

For basic Flutter widget architecture, the [getting started tutorial](https://flutter.io/get-started/codelab/) on flutter.io is useful.

[Google's Youtube playlist for Flutter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fq4N0hgOWzU&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIJ7dsVN4iRuA7BT8XHzGtCr) has some good starting points.

For handling data and state, there's the [reactive architecture I/O video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RS36gBEp8OI) with an accompanying [post](https://medium.com/flutter-io/build-reactive-mobile-apps-in-flutter-companion-article-13950959e381).

Brian Egan's [architecture samples](http://fluttersamples.com/) isa great resource.

There are getting started guides for both [Android devs](https://flutter.io/flutter-for-android/) and [iOS devs](https://flutter.io/flutter-for-ios/).

And the [Flutter Cookbook](https://flutter.io/cookbook/) is a great place to see how to implement common mobile patterns.